# Is there a way to code in Swift to track and log the time spend in apps by the user?

Tags: swift, facebook, logging, event-tracking

Some of you may know the app "QualityTime" an app where users can track their behavior (time) spend on a all their apps. Does anyone know if there is a way to implement this in swift 3 so I can use this in my app project? I want to keep track of the users time spend on Facebook, twitter or Instagram for example and present this information in my app.

To make this even more elaborate; is there a way to keep track of how many pictures are uploaded by the user to Instagram for example?

Thank you guys! very curious to hear what you have to say about this.